# JQuery equivalent in prototype

Tags: javascript, jquery, serialization, prototypejs

What is the form.serialize equivalent in JQuery if there is one?

```
$('person-example').serialize()
// -> 'username=sulien&age=22&hobbies=coding&hobbies=hiking'

$('person-example').serialize(true)
// -> {username: 'sulien', age: '22', hobbies: ['coding', 'hiking']}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the same, however you have to put `#` before your selector to select certain ID

```
$('#person-example').serialize();
```

Comment: Prototype's `$` function is basically an alias for `document.getElementById`. Not sure where you got the class selector idea from...

Comment: from when? That's isn't true. If you'd use his one, it would search for tagName person-example, not his Id

Comment: You're confusing Prototype's `$` and jQuery's `$`. http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/dollar/